# QGIS Server Postgis Connection - (WMS) 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: gis, openlayers, postgis, qgis

I am working on a map application and created a WMS layer using QGIS Server and postgis.

About a week ago, I opened the wms layer with the browser using the openlayers library. but for a few days. I am getting the error in the picture. I did not change the postgis passwords or anything, but the image does not come.

I didn't make any changes to the .qgs file either. I can't find what is causing the error. anybody can help me :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I open a url of the wms layer in the browser, I get a 'layers not invalid' error.

Comment: I think you are in the wrong site. This site is about programming. We have a sister site about GIS, it may be more relevant. Note: your dialog is connection about postgis, not the web to a tiling service (I doubt it is built-in in qgis, probably it is an extra program in QGIS distribution)

Comment: And: do not add information in comments. Edit you question to add any new information